# Can results of models fit to multiply imputed datasets be extracted to a dataframe?

Tags: r, linear-regression, missing-data, r-mice, broom

Is it possible to extract to a dataframe the pooled estimates from several models fit to multiply imputed data?

Below is how I perform this for a complete case dataframe (i.e. with no missing data) - I would like to do a similar process to extract similar results of several models fit to imputed data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(mice)

data <- nhanes
sapply(data, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) #check missing data
data <- data %>% filter(bmi !="NA" & hyp != "NA" & chl != "NA") # remove missing data

out <-c("bmi")
exp <- c("chl","age","factor(hyp)")

#run models and extract to tidy data frame
models <- expand.grid(out, exp) %>%
group_by(Var1) %>% rowwise() %>%
summarise(frm = paste0(Var1, "~", Var2)) %>%
group_by(model_id = row_number(),frm) %>%
do(tidy(lm(.$frm, data = data))) %>%
mutate(lci = estimate-(1.96*std.error),
     uci = estimate+(1.96*std.error))
```

Below is an example of imputing the missing data using `mice` and fitting just a single regression model:

```
# Impute missing data using mice
data <- nhanes
imp <- mice(data, print = F)

#Fit single model
fit <- with(imp, lm(bmi ~ chl))

#Get pooled estimates
a <- pool(fit)

summary(a)
```

Comment: Do you want one model for each imputed dataset?

Comment: Thanks - ultimately I would like to get the overall pooled estimate after fitting a model to each imputed dataset. Is it possible to use 'pool' with your code - I think will need to convert back to a 'mids' after running the 5 models in order to execute 'pool'?

Comment: You want to fit different model for each `mids`?

Comment: I want to get the pooled estimate. In my example above, this is achieved by executing 'pool(fit)' after running 'fit <- with(imp, lm(bmi ~ chl))'... As in below your output produces a result for each dataset where instead I would like to get the pooled estimate

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is to start with `complete(imp, "long")` since it provides all the imputed datasets. After doing that, you have to play a bit with some `tidyverse` and `broom` functions especially `nest()` and `tidy()` which are very helpful here. Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(mice)
data <- nhanes # data
imp <- mice(data, print = F) # imputation
# complete data
data.complete <- complete(imp, "long")  
glimpse(data.complete) # all the 5 imputations are here

data.complete %>% 
        select(-.id) %>% 
        nest(-.imp) %>%
        mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(bmi ~ chl, data = .)),
               tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>%
        unnest(tidied) %>%
        filter(term == "chl") %>%
        mutate(adjusted = p.adjust(p.value),
               lci = estimate-(1.96*std.error),
               uci = estimate+(1.96*std.error))
# output
  .imp term   estimate  std.error statistic     p.value   adjusted           lci        uci
1    1  chl 0.01972747 0.01755024  1.124057 0.272584078 0.45430932 -0.0146709916 0.05412594
2    2  chl 0.02133664 0.01719462  1.240891 0.227154661 0.45430932 -0.0123648105 0.05503808
3    3  chl 0.03070542 0.01534959  2.000407 0.057397701 0.22512674  0.0006202261 0.06079062
4    4  chl 0.04109955 0.02044568  2.010183 0.056281686 0.22512674  0.0010260220 0.08117308
5    5  chl 0.05448964 0.01585764  3.436175 0.002251967 0.01125984  0.0234086522 0.08557062
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to apply Rubin's rules here to get the pooled estimates?